# Why does wordpress still strip my query var?

Tags: url-rewriting, query, urls, rewrite-rules

Im trying to pass a query var to a custom page template with pretty permalinks.

So basically i have a page called "albums". And i want to pass a query var to that page called "type". So the non-pretty version would be mywebsite.com/index.php?p=97&type=vinyl

the "pretty" version would the be mywebsite.com/albums/vinyls

And the template need to then retrieve that variable (i.e. vinyls)

I have read a lot on this all day, but still cant get it to work. So i was hoping some kind soul here would help me out.

So first im adding the rewrite to my functions.php:

```
function addrewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^albums/([^/]+)/?$',
    'index.php?p=97&type=$matches[1]',
    'top' );
}
add_action('init', 'addrewrite');
```

This seems to work as i can see it turn up if a get a var_dump of all the rewrites.

Now if i do a test and type mywebsite.com/albums/vinyl into my browser
wordpress strips the last bit "vinyl" away. I read a couple of places that this is because i need to register the query var too. so i did that with the following code:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_my_var');
function add_my_var($public_query_vars) {
  $public_query_vars[] = 'type';
  return $public_query_vars;
}
```

Then i flushed the permalinks by pressing save in the **settings** -> **permalinks**, yet wordpress still strips my url.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a page, change `p=97` to `page_id=97` or `pagename=albums`. `p` is for the `post` post type.

I also suggest changing your query var to something more unique.

Comment: Thank you so much! that did the trick. I do find it strange that wordpress was able to find the correct PAGE, even though i was rewriting to a POST. But now my query var works.

Comment: I do have one question though. When i generate permalinks to these pages how do i then make sure that it will work no matter wether "pretty permalinks" is turned on or not. If i link to albums/vinyl - then it only works if prettyP is on, And if i link to ?page_id=97&type=vinyl - it only works when prettyP is off. What is the best practice to get around that?

Comment: what you were seeing was your request resulting in a 404, which then causes WP to run the [canonical redirect function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/redirect_canonical), which does a LIKE query for your request and forwards there if something similar is found. `page_id` should work regardless of pretty permalinks being on or off, but you can also check the state of permalinks by looking at the option `permalink_structure`, it will be empty if pretty permalinks are off.

Comment: yeah "page_id" works because its native wordpress, but how do i get "type" to behave the same way? has that got to do with the permalink_structure? im just wondering what a permalink should end up looking like in the code. probable something lige: `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>vinyls">link</a>` or what? thats not suppose to work with permalinks off is it?

Comment: I think you'll have to build them manually by checking if the `permalink_structure` option is not empty, otherwise use [`add_query_arg`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg) to append type.